# Обновить счетчик на кнопке telegram bot C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обновить счетчик на кнопке в сообщениях от бота Telegram? Хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку + счетчик на этой кнопке увеличивался и сообщение обновлялось

```
 var inlineKeyboard = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                {
                    new [] 
                    {
                        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(i.ToString(),"callback+"),
                    }
                });

        if (e.Message.Text != null)
        {
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
                          chatId: e.Message.Chat,
                          text: "choose",
                          replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard);
        }
```

Что нужно дописать в обработчике, чтобы сообщение обновилось?

```
 botClient.OnCallbackQuery += async (object sc, CallbackQueryEventArgs ev) =>
        {
            var message = ev.CallbackQuery.Message;
            if (ev.CallbackQuery.Data == "callback+")
            {
                i++;
                await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(ev.CallbackQuery.Id, "+1", false);
            }                
        };
```

Comment: А что за "кнопка telegram-bot"? Где она находится?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/2-0-intro

Answer (score 0):

Для обновления счётчика на кнопке нужно отправлять новую кнопку. Редактирование сообщения осуществляется командой [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext)

```
await botClient.EditMessageTextAsync(chatId, messageId, your_edited_message, replyMarkup: NewKeyboardWithCounter);
```